# Criar arquivo sem saber diretório? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arquivo

Sabe-se que é possível criar um novo arquivo por meio de Python através de `file_create = open(r'C:\Diretório\Diretório...\FileName', 'w')`. Todavia, é necessário indicar onde esse arquivo será criado no computador.

Se quiséssemos criar um arquivo em um computador desconhecido, que fará download do programa Python, como isso seria possível? Considerando que para originar conteúdo que fique em um local específico e/ou explicíto no computador (Desktop ou alguma pasta), precisa-se dos três elementos que precedem o 'Desktop' em C:\Users\Windows 7\Desktop: o 'C', o 'Users', e o nome de usuário utilizado.

Há algum comando geral? Ou que pergunte ao usuário onde quer que os dados fiquem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Você pode pegar do sistema o nome do usuário do computador usando getpass. Veja:

```
import getpass
usuario = getpass.getuser()
```

Aí você pode tentar algo parecido com isto:

```
file_create = open("C:\\Users\\" + usuario + "\\Desktop\\filename", "w")
```

Comment: Obrigado! Uma dúvida geral: o C:\Users\ será igual para todo computador Windows, ou pode variar também?

Comment: Eu pelo menos nunca vi variar. Em teoria é pra ser sempre C:\Users\..., mas não poderia dar 100% de garantia.